# querying sqlite database using "between" with cursor

Tags: android-studio, cursor, android-sqlite

newbie here.. i have a two data sets which is "time-in", and "time-out" and i would like to query this two using "between" so that the data ive should get was the filtered on my "time-in" to my "time-out"...

this is my query data (get all data).

```
public Cursor retrieveHistoryLocationFromLocalDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String[] columnNames =
            {
                    HISTORY_SERIAL_NUMBER,
                    HISTORY_LATITUDE,
                    HISTORY_LONGITUDE,
                    HISTORY_DATE_TIME,
                    HISTORY_SPEED,
                    HISTORY_PORT
            };



            return (db.query(TABLE_HISTORY_FLEET_LOCATION, columnNames,null, 
            null,null, null, null));
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rawQuery()` method to prepare select statement.

```java
public Cursor retrieveHistoryLocationFromLocalDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, String timeIn, String {

    String sql = "SELECT HISTORY_SERIAL_NUMBER, HISTORY_LATITUDE,"
                    + " HISTORY_LONGITUDE, HISTORY_DATE_TIME, HISTORY_SPEED, HISTORY_PORT"
                    + " FROM your_table_name"
                    + " WHERE your_time_in_out_column BETWEEN '" + timeIn + "' AND '" + timeOut + "'";

    return (db.rawQuery(sql, null));
}
```

You have to change `your_table_name` with your actual table name and `your_time_in_out_column` with actual column name and `timeIn` and `timeOut` variable type, values with your actual values.

While calling `retrieveHistoryLocationFromLocalDatabase()` method you need to pass 3 parameters SQLite database object, time-in and time-out.

PS: `rawQuery()` method is not recommended as it takes raw SQL statements as an argument. This poses SQL injection threat.

Comment: how about passing may data  from my main activity to my database helper?because my "someVlaues" was set in my  activity and i cant use intent/use shared preference thru java object only..

Comment: btw, you're awesome @Shashanth  you always help me in my problem cases.. thank you and cheers :)

Comment: Updated my answer check it. Add extra 2 parameters to `retrieveHistoryLocationFromLocalDatabase()` method and pass values to those arguments from activity.